# How to capture google map screenshot in flutter web app?

Tags: flutter, dictionary, google-maps, web, screenshot

I am trying to capture the screenshot of google map in flutter web app using below code.

```
Future capture(GlobalKey key, GoogleMapController controller) async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
        key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;

    final image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: devicePixalRatio);

    _saveScreenShot(image);
  }

 _saveScreenShot(ui.Image img) async {
    var byteData = await img.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    var pngBytes = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();

    final _base64 = base64Encode(pngBytes);
    final anchor = html.AnchorElement(
        href: 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,$_base64')
      ..download = "image.png"
      ..target = 'blank';

    html.document.body!.append(anchor);
    anchor.click();
    anchor.remove();
  }
```

But it is throwing below exception

Error: Unexpected null value.
at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:55339/dart_sdk.js:5067:11)
at Object.nullCheck (http://localhost:55339/dart_sdk.js:5394:30)
at _engine.PlatformViewLayer.new.preroll (http://localhost:55339/dart_sdk.js:147919:12)
at _engine.OffsetEngineLayer.new.prerollChildren (http://localhost:55339/dart_sdk.js:147259:15)
at _engine.OffsetEngineLayer.new.preroll (http://localhost:55339/dart_sdk.js:147555:35)
at _engine.OffsetEngineLayer.new.prerollChildren (http://localhost:55339/dart_sdk.js:147259:15)
at _engine.OffsetEngineLayer.new.preroll (http://localhost:55339/dart_sdk.js:147555:35)
at _engine.TransformEngineLayer.new.prerollChildren (http://localhost:55339/dart_sdk.js:147259:15)
at _engine.TransformEngineLayer.new.preroll (http://localhost:55339/dart_sdk.js:147555:35)
at _engine.RootLayer.new.prerollChildren (http://localhost:55339/dart_sdk.js:147259:15)
at _engine.RootLayer.new.preroll

**Please Note**
mapController.takeSnapshot() doesn't support the Flutter Web & I cannot use google static map api due to my requirement.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @MátyásGrőger thanks for suggestions.. done